# Why does my select @@rowcount return a SqlException of Subquery returned more than 1 value?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have an application that calls a stored proc that does the following:

```
update tableA set duedate=@duedate where id=@id;
select @@RowCount;
```

On deployment of my application on the client's server, I am getting an error of:

"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used on the expression"

I am using in C# the command:

```
executeScalar(...)
```

Is there something that I seem to be missing with configurations? I have tested it on my server and it seems to work fine.

EDIT: Whole stored proc

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateDueDates
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@batchNumber varchar(15),
@dueDate date
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
update dbo.ItemTable
set DUEDATE = @dueDate
where
BATCHNUMBER = @batchNumber;

-- Returns the number of Updates
select @@ROWCOUNT;
END
GO
```

Comment: Why have you tagged it with both mysql and sql-server? They are different products.

Comment: Show  code of you SP.

Comment: Try setting `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the begining of the SP

Comment: Are you sure that's all that's in your stored proc?

Comment: Yes. Thats why it's workign on my dev server but not on theirs. Which confuses me.. it's just a simple update statement..

Comment: Is there a Trigger on TableA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is there is an update trigger on TableA. I've seen many triggers written that assume rows get inserted or updated one at a time. When you execute an update statement that updates more than one row, the trigger fails.

Comment: Thank you. There's a trigger on their side for that particular table which has select statements in it. I will have to rewrite my scripts then.

Comment: Any Advice on how to do this? The only thing i can think of is writing a seaprate stroed proc to do a select count(1) of the parameters passed in?

Comment: Are you sure it's the @@Rowcount that is throwing the error? I think it's probably the update.

Comment: Ya it's the update. But because the update is doing several select statements this will mess up the executeScalar(). My workaround at the moment is to use a executeNonQuery() on the update and use a select count(1) afterwards to see the number of rows that SHOULD have been updated.

Comment: I think the long term solution is to have someone re-write the trigger so it properly handles update statements that effect multiple rows.